# Is it possible to add custom authentication middleware on python based azure function API

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

While developing an API using python based azure function. ***I have come across a situation where I have to implement custom JWT authentication and authorization middleware.***

I have tried to use [python worker extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-configuration#python-worker-extensions) *pre_invocation_app_level method.* However, I am not able to pass the verification result to the endpoint or return from the middleware in case of invalid user.

Sample source code:

```
from azure.functions import AppExtensionBase, Context
import typing
from logging import Logger
import azure.functions as func


class AuthMiddleware(AppExtensionBase):
    @classmethod
    def pre_invocation_app_level(
        cls,
        logger: Logger,
        context: Context,
        func_args: typing.Dict[str, object] = ...,
        *args,
        **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
        req = func_args.get("req")
        auth_header = req.headers.get("Authorization")
        if not auth_header:
            return func.HttpResponse(
                "Unauthorized", status_code=401, headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Custom"}
            )
```